# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars and nans in array

Tags: python

I've got an algorithm for calculating Bessel's function and an error RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars keeps popping up

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>
> r[i][j] = r[i][j-1] + (r[i][j-1]-r[i-1][j-1])/(4**j-1)

I also got an array that looks like this, obviously I don't want any nans out there.

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]                                                                                     

 [nan  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]                                                                                     
 [nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]                                                                                     
 [nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]                                                                                     
 [nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]                                                                                     
 [nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

 [nan nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.]                                                                                     
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.]                                                                                     
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.]                                                                                     
 [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  0.]]
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

def romberg(f,a,b,n):
    i=0
    j=0
    h = float(b) - float(a)

    r[i][j] = (float(h/2)) * (f(float(a)) + f(float(b)))
    for i in range(n):
        h=h/2
        sum=float(0)
        for k in range(2**i-1):
          k=float(1)
          sum = float(sum) + f(float(a + k*h))
    r[i][0]=(float(1/2))*r[i-1][0] + sum*h
    for j in range(i):
        # error occurs on this line:
        r[i][j] = r[i][j-1] + (r[i][j-1]-r[i-1][j-1])/(4**j-1)
        
def funkcja(t):
  return np.cos(np.sin(t))/np.pi

r = np.zeros((10, 10))
wynik=romberg(funkcja,0,np.pi,10)
print(r)
```

What should be changed here?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure because the code is technically valid either way, but it looks like the formatting got a bit messed up and that the `r[i][0]=...` line and the loop below it were meant to be indented and inside the `for i` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `range(n)` gives you a list from 0 to `n-1`, inclusive. So `4**j-1` will evaluate to 0 the first time through the loop, which leads to an attempt to divide by zero.

It looks like the code expects both `range` invocations to be of the form `range(1, n)` instead.